# Recurrence Relation: Solve T(n) = 25T(n/5) + ((n log 5) / (log n))^2

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

T(n) = 25T(n/5) + ((n log 5) / (log n))^2

I am new to recurrence relation and was stuck on solving this above question and would like to seek some direction!

I do not think that I am able to apply master theorem here which leads me to use the telescoping series where I was able to reduce the relation (by dividing by n^2 log^2 5) to the form of T(n) = T(1)/1 + (1/2)^2 + (1/4)^2 + ... + (1/logn)^2. After which I was not able to further simplify further.

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Rethink the applicability of the master theorem.  `a = 25`, `b = 5`, `c = log_b(a) = 2`.  That puts you in case 2c of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

After `n = 5^m`the recurrence can be recast as

`r[m] = 25*r[m-1]+(5^m/m)^2`

now this is a linear and the solution can be obtained as

`r[n] = rh[m] + rp[m]`

The homogeneous has the solution

`rh[m] = 5^(2*m)c0`

and to obtain a particular solution we proceed by considering

`rp[m] = 5^(2*m)c0[m]`

and after substitution

`5^(2*m)c0[m] =  5^2*5^(2*(m-1))c0[m-1] + (5^(2*m)/m)^2`

or simplifying

`c0[m] = c0[m-1] + 1/m^2`

with solution

`c0[m] = pi^2/6 - PolyGamma[1,1,m]`

then

`rp[m] = 5^(2*m)*(pi^2/6 - PolyGamma[1,1,m])`

and finally

`r[m] = (pi^2/6 - PolyGamma[1,1,m] + c0)*5^(2*m)`

the backwards step needed to obtain `T[n]` is left to the reader.